# Getting undefined params in my compoment with generateStaticParams nextjs 13. How to pass them correctly?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm using the App router of nextjs 13, with typescript, and I'm trying to create dynamic pages and generate the paths for them with generateStaticParams().

The function generateStaticParams() seems to work, and it collects the correct information. But when I want to use the information in my component, I get a undefined value.

The page is fetchting the data correctly if I hardcode the ID, so I only need to swap this for the ID collected with the generateStaticParams.

**How can I make sure that the page is receiving the data from generateStaticParams?**

```
/src/app/coffeeplaces/[coffeeplace]/page.tsx
```

```
import fetchCoffeePlace from "@/api/fetchCoffeeplace";
import { db } from "@/helpers/firebaseConfig";
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import Image from "next/image";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import ImagesCarousel from "./components/imagesCarousel";
import Link from "next/link";
import CoffeeMainDetails from "./components/coffeeMainDetails";

export default async function Page({ params }: { params: { id: string, slug: string } }) {
  const { id, slug } = params

  // this comes back UNDEFINED
  console.log('id', params.id) // or id
  console.log('slug', params.slug) // or slug

  // This hardcoded option works to fetch the data
  // const id = 'r7CFv3t4Ni5sNl20wE8h'

  const CoffeeplaceData = fetchCoffeePlace(id);
  const CoffeeplaceInfoData = fetchCoffeePlace(id); // 

  const coffeeplace = await CoffeeplaceData;

  return (
    <div>
      <Link href={'/coffeeplaces'} className="text-sm font-light">Back to listing</Link>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <CoffeeplaceInfo promise={CoffeeplaceInfoData} />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}

async function CoffeeplaceInfo({ promise, }: { promise: Promise<CoffeePlace>; }) {
  const coffeeplaceInfo = await promise;
  return (
      <>
      <div className="pt-6 lg:flex w-full">
        <ImagesCarousel featuredImage={coffeeplaceInfo.featuredImage} />
        <CoffeeMainDetails name={coffeeplaceInfo.name} priceRange={coffeeplaceInfo.priceRange} organic={coffeeplaceInfo.organic} fairTrade={coffeeplaceInfo.fairTrade}/>
      </div>
      </>
    )
}

export async function generateStaticParams() { // tried with this: generateStaticParams({ params: { id, slug }}: any)
  const coffeePlaces = await getDocs(collection(db, "coffeePlaces"));
  const data = coffeePlaces.docs.map((doc) => ({
    id: doc.id,
    ...doc.data()
  }));

  var slugify = require('slugify')

  const result = data.map((item) => {
    const slug = slugify(item.name, {
      replacement: '-',  
      lower: true,  
      strict: true,
    });

    // these are logging the correct values
    console.log(item.id);
    console.log(slug);
    
    return {
      params: {
        id: item.id,
        slug: slug
      }
    };
  }); 

  // this is logging the correct result
  // [{ params: { id: '9ZVOCYsngTksBKXqQQOH', slug: 'coffeeplace-1' } }, { params: { id: 'r7CFv3t4Ni5sNl20wE8h', slug: 'example-2' } } ]

  return result; 
}
```

[Using parallel Data Fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching#parallel-data-fetching)

Small other thing, might be related, in the generateStaticParams function, when I loop over the result, for the item.name it says: `Property 'name' does not exist on type '{ id: string; }')`

**Edit: Trying out with new environment**

I've created a new nextjs project to test this out, and got the same results.

1. I installed Nextjs 13 app router, typescript and tailwind with `npx create-next-app@latest my-project --typescript --eslint`
2. I created a folder structure like so `src/app/books/[type]/[book-id]/page.tsx`, and used the following example to test it: [Example of generateStaticParams](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/44641#discussioncomment-4849823)

When I log the results I get an **unidentified** and when I build with `npm run build` it doesn't show the build of the pages.

[Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/long-bird-2r3q7q)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mismatch between dynamic segment name and what you expect in the code. The naming should be consistent between folder name and what you expect in the code.

You have `coffeeplace` segment (`/src/app/coffeeplaces/[coffeeplace]/page.tsx`) in the file system, but for some reason you want to pass `id` and `slug` keys from the `generateStaticParams` function. You can't do that, the key that you are passing from `generateStaticParams` should also be named `coffeeplace` and in your case it's the single key, you can't pass more info, other keys etc.

Info from the docs:

> `generateStaticParams` should return an array of objects where each object represents the populated dynamic segments of a single route.
>
> Each property in the object is a dynamic segment to be filled in for the route.
> The properties name is the segment's name, and the properties value is what that segment should be filled in with.
>
> `/product/[id]` -> `{ id: string }[]`
>
> `/products/[category]/[product]` -> `{ category: string, product: string }[]`
>
> `/products/[...slug]` -> `{ slug: string[] }[]`

[More in the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params#returns)

Comment: Hi Danila, thank you very much! A small thing, with a big impact, that I completely overlooked. But does this mean that I can only use the key as param? It builds the pages now, but with the ID as url. But I would like to have the slug as url, but still use the ID to fetch the correct info for that page - hence the 2 params. Think that's possible?

Comment: @Bart it's not possible right now as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

your `result` array has this format

```
result=[params: {id: "id_1",slug: "slug_1"},params: {id: "id_2",slug: "slug_2"},.....]
```

when you reach `params` in `Page` component, you should be using,

```
const { id, slug } = params.params
```

because `params` in each dynamic page is

```
 params=params: {id: "id_1",slug: "slug_1"}
```

Comment: Hi @Yilmaz, thanks for your help! I've played around with this, but it also shows a **undefined** unfortunately. When I console log just `params`, without .params, .id, or .slug, it logs whatever I have currently written in the url. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**you are only allowed to use the params that are in [ ] and nothing else**

so your component must have:

- "use client" at top of component, not page.js (your not allowed to combine clent and server side in page.js)
- component need params for example: id, and in your component you add the the api call to fetch using component id parameter useEffect useState ...
- last thing you go to page.js call getStaticParams() (get it from documentation ) return only id as specified, and in Page down call your component and pass it that id that is passed to Page as param